# Как узнать размер клавиатуры в мобильной веб-версии на JS?

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью JS я могу узнать размер клавиатуры в моб. версии сайта?

Comment: никак. а зачем это может понадобиться?

Comment: @Grundy, я использую PWA приложения, делаю мессенджер, и проблема в том, что когда клавиатура появляется - всё уходит вверх, пробовал делать через position: fixed;, но она то фиксируется, но сам сайт просто вверх поднимается, а не сам контент, и поэтому думал через костыль пробовать как-то...

Comment: а какое поведение ожидается при открытие клавиатуры? учитывая что она не является частью окна